# JSON String Validation [Spring Boot] - Constraining zero values

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Currently, I'm retrieving a userId from JSON and making sure it isn't blank.

```
@NotBlank
private String userId;
```

The `@NotBlank` annotation gives us a valid check for an empty value but we'd also like to check that a 0 isn't given for this value also.  I know `@Positive` works for integers but I was curious if something existed for a String, outside of creating a custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

With `@NotBlank` use `@Pattern(regexp = "/^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$/")` also.

Pattern `/^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$/` is used for positive numbers, you can change based on your requirement.